# find error in code below spring mvc code

Tags: spring-mvc

1.The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." I am completely new to SpringMVC and not able to solve this 404 please help me so that i can move forward to learn the subject . I tried everything that i got on internet

> index.jsp

```
<%response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
 %>
<html>
<body>
<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

> first-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd      
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc      
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
     <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
     <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.Tutorial"></ctx:component-scan>
     <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
 </beans>
```

> web.xml

```
  <web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

> AddControllerTYpe.java

```
 package com.Tutorial.FirstWebProject;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 @Controller
 public class AddControllerType 
 {
      @RequestMapping("/add")
     public void add()
     {  
         System.out.println("-----its here-----");
     }
 }
```